# Ember View not responding to user initiated events

Tags: javascript, ember.js, dom-events

Can anyone explain why the events I've put on my `SampleView` aren't working?

http://jsfiddle.net/colinkahn/3nkUv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you override the init method, you should call the super method `this._super()`. Here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3nkUv/8/